# Regex in python to differentiate between merger and demerger

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have a following code. I am trying to differentiate merger with demerger. But it is not working as expected.

Expected result is, first three should be **True** and last three should be **False**. But instead last two is returning **True**.

Any suggestons?

```
import re

def is_merger(text):

  pattern = r"\b(?!de[\s\-]*)merger\b"

  if re.search(pattern, text, re.IGNORECASE):
    return True
  else:
    return False

print(is_merger("this a merger"))
print(is_merger("merger"))
print(is_merger("Merger"))
print(is_merger("this is demerger"))
print(is_merger("this is a de merger"))
print(is_merger("this is de-merger"))
```

Comment: What if it's a "merger and also de-merger"?

Comment: You just need a lookbehind. `r"\b(?<!de[\s-])(?<!de)merger\b"`

Comment: @Nick - Currently, all it needs to do is determine whether it is a merger or not, even if it has a demerger.  The basic structure of my actions is as follows.

ACTION_MAPPING = {
    "DIVIDEND": r"dividend|divdend|dividned|int div|interim div|div|ividend",
    "BONUS": r"bonus",
    "SPLIT": r"split|fv split|splt",
    "DEMERGER": r"demerger|de-merger|de merger",
    "MERGER": r"\b(?<!de[\s-])(?<!de)merger\b",
    "RIGHTS": r"rights",
    "BUYBACK": r"buyback|buy back|buy-back"
}